# Matrix differentiation, $x^T A x$ w.r.t $A$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

In Gaussian Mixture Models, in order to derive the M-step for covariance matrix, I need this result. I have poor knowledge of matrix calculus and result does not exist in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

What is the partial derivative of $x^T A x$ w.r.t $A$?

Comment: The section on scalar-by-matrix seems as if it would work here, because $x^TAx$ is a scalar.  It might be tedious to write out all the components but it should work.

Comment: You can just do it component wise in the worst case scenario. In this case, if you do it component wise you see that $\partial{x^T Ax}/\partial{A_{ij}} = x_i \cdot x_j$. So the ultimate answer would be $xx^T$

Comment: Here I'm assuming $x$ is a column vector. And I'm using the "denominator convention" as written in the wikipedia article. Otherwise it would be the transpose of that in the other notation.

Comment: This function is linear in $A$, so it is its own derivative.

Comment: Echoing @JannikPitt's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$x'Ax = \mathrm{tr}(xx'A)  = xx':A,$$ where $:$ is a scalar product on the space of matrices. The derivative wrt $A$ is thus $xx'$.